# How to use QtExec in Wix to run cmd file in quite mode

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I googled lot but I couldn't find any working examples on quite execution. What I want is run a .cmd file in quite mode. I did the following,

```
<CustomAction Id ="QtExecCommandLine" 
              Property="QtExec23" 
              Value="&quot;C:\my\Bats\MakeFolder.cmd&quot;"
              Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id ="QtExec23" 
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="check"
              Impersonate="no"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="QtExecCommandLine" Before="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
  <Custom Action="QtExec23" After="QtExecCommandLine"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The above code get compiled successfully but MakeFolder.cmd file doesn't run (If it does, a folder should be created)

I read many post but according to them the only thing that I understand is to use WixUtil library with `BinaryKey=WixCA` and `DllEntry=CAQuiteExec`.

I don't know what am I doing wrong? Please I Need your help.

Comment: I am wondering whether the problem is, I haven't specified to run this command in cmd.exe Or is it decided by the specified Dll?

Comment: I replaces Value="something.exe" for Value="&quot;something.exe&quot;" as mentioned in [link](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/standard-libraries/silence-please#comment-53) Then it gives an error in event viewer as `Installation success or error status: 1603.`